# Como faço para acessar corretamente elementos de uma matriz dinâmica via ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz, memória

Como muitos sabem (creio eu) uma matriz multidimensional é armazenada na memória de forma linear, ou seja, cada linha da matriz vai na memória uma em seguida da outra. Para exemplificar eu elaborei a seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo assim, é possível manipular uma matriz multidimensional como se fosse um vetor usando um ponteiro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 4
#define COLUMNS 4

int main(void){

    int matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS]={{17, 10, 14, 78},
                               {4, 14, 15, 10},
                               {14, 45, 56, 70},
                               {47, 15, 49, 10}};

    int *ptr=matrix[0];

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<(ROWS*COLUMNS); i++){

        printf("[%d] ", ptr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    ptr=NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Sabendo disso, eu tentei aplicar esse mesmo conceito a uma matriz bidimensional que foi alocada dinamicamente, porém na hora de acessar os elementos via comando `for` (como no exemplo acima) eu acabei recebendo lixo na saída, ou seja, valores que não estavam na matriz. Segue o código do "programa":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 4
#define COLUMNS 4

int main(void){

    int **matrix=(int**)malloc(ROWS*sizeof(int*)); //Alocando as linhas da matriz

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<ROWS; i++){

        matrix[i]=(int*)malloc(COLUMNS*sizeof(int)); //Alocando as colunas
    }

    //Preenchendo a matriz
    for(unsigned int row=0; row<ROWS; row++){

        for(unsigned int column=0; column<COLUMNS; column++){

             matrix[row][column]=42; //42? Seria isso a resposta para "tudo"?
        }
    }

    int *ptr=matrix[0];

    //Exibindo valores
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<(ROWS*COLUMNS); i++){

        printf("[%d] ", ptr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    for(unsigned int column=0; column<COLUMNS; column++){

        free(matrix[column]); //Desalocando as colunas da matriz
    }

    free(matrix); //Desalocando as linhas da matriz
    ptr=NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Quando executo o código:

```
[42] [42] [42] [42] [-2074264339] [134268537] [42] [42] [42] [42] [-2074264339] [134268537] [42] [42] [42] [42]
```

Por que o resultado exibido não é parecido com o do primeiro código? O que há de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há nada de "errado", somente que na alocação dinâmica, os dados são armazenados de forma diferente (não linear).

No seu exemplo, ao invés de um bloco de tamanho `ROWS*COLUMNS`, são alocados 4 ponteiros do tipo `int`, apontando para 4 vetores de inteiros.

Aqui, você aloca os 4 ponteiros:

```
int **matrix = (int**)malloc(ROWS*sizeof(int*));
```

E aqui, você aloca os 4 vetores:

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i<ROWS; i++){
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(COLUMNS*sizeof(int));
}
```

O esquema da memória fica da seguinte forma (exemplo):

```
  ptr
   |
   V
+-------+     +---------+---------+---------+--------+
| *ROW0 |---->| COLUMN0 | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |COLUMN3 |
+-------+     +---------+---------+---------+--------+ 
| *ROW1 |---->| COLUMN0 | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |COLUMN3 |
+-------+     +---------+---------+---------+--------+ 
| *ROW2 |---->| COLUMN0 | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |COLUMN3 |
+-------+     +---------+---------+---------+--------+ 
| *ROW3 |---->| COLUMN0 | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |COLUMN3 |
+-------+     +---------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Como `ptr` aponta para o primeiro vetor, os 4 primeiros elementos são 42, porém, logo em seguida, o que é impresso é um endereço de memória (2 posições de 32bits) seguido dos próximos 4 elementos e outro endereço e assim por diante.

Por isso, não é possível percorrer a matriz da mesma forma (linear).

Inclusive, não há garantia de que os dados serão alocados na forma do bloco do exemplo acima, pois o `malloc` pode alocar os blocos em posições diferentes do *heap*, conforme a necessidade (ex: se a memória estiver fragmentada).

Referência sobre fragmentação (em inglês): [Dynamic Memory Allocation and Fragmentation in C and C++](https://www.design-reuse.com/articles/25090/dynamic-memory-allocation-fragmentation-c.html)

Comment: De quem é exatamente esses endereços impressos?

Comment: São os endereços do próximo vetor, conforme o desenho acima. Mas, como eu disse na resposta, não há garantia de que os valores impressos sejam sempre esses. O `malloc` pode alocar os blocos em locais diferentes

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz umas pequenas modificações no seu código, não sei exatamente se está certo ou não também, mas o resultado bateu com o que você queria.

O que eu fiz foi, na declaração da variável ptr, adicionar um outro asterisco e transformar em um ponteiro de ponteiros, tal qual a sua variável matriz, e atribuir com a variável em si, não com a primeira linha ou com o primeiro elemento.
Também modifiquei o for que imprimia, usando duas variáveis i e j para selecionar o elemento pretendido da matriz.

Ficou assim a parte alterada:

```
int **ptr = matrix;

//Exibindo valores
for(unsigned int i=0; i<(ROWS); i++){
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++){
        printf("[%d] ", ptr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Estou aprendendo também, então qualquer coisa, fico feliz em ser corrigido ou complementado.